# Find f(32) given f(x) = f(x-1) + 2^(f(x-1)+1) and f(0) = 5

Tags: functions, recursion, tetration

I would like to find f(32) given:

f(x) = f(x-1) + 2^(f(x-1)+1)

f(0) = 5

I figured that this function grows tetrationally (if that is a word) but I don't really know

Where I got this equation from:

In the collectable trading card game Magic: The Gathering, there are these cards:

[Miirym, sentinel wyrm](https://scryfall.com/card/clb/284/miirym-sentinel-wyrm),
[Astral Dragon](https://scryfall.com/card/clb/664/astral-dragon),
[Parallel Lives](https://scryfall.com/card/isd/199/parallel-lives)

If Astral Dragon where to come into play with Miirym and Parallel Lives already on the battlefield and all of the tokens Astral Dragon created where copies of Parallel Lives, you would end up with f(32) Parallel Lives in play.

Edit: I am not looking for a specific answer, just a rough estimate of how large that number is. I know it is larger than 2^^32 bit is it Larger than 2^^33? 2^^34?

Comment: What are you hoping for here?  Obviously the answer is very, very large.

Comment: @lulu Just a range. Ie. is it somewhere between 2^^32 and 2^^33? Or is it larger than that?

Comment: Without specific estimates, this seems like a googolplex-like number. Writing out the decimal digits or the number of digits or the number of digits in the number of digits might be too long for a post.

Comment: I would like to know who did downvote this question. Cheer you up, make some tea and relax.

Comment: Funnily enough I appear to have been the first to pose this question on some Stack Exchange: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117010/magic-the-gathering-projecting-images

Comment: Perhaps the "very large number calculator" ("Hypercalc") can help here. Try https://mrob.com/pub/perl/hypercalc.html (Robert Munafo). Would like  to know myself, whether that calculator can do this...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms That worked! The result was 30 PT (3.553934904655 × 10^20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Hypercalc](https://mrob.com/pub/perl/hypercalc.html) at the suggestion of [Gottfried Helms](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1714/gottfried-helms)

The answer is 30 PT (3.553934904655 × 10^20)

Which means a power tower of 10s, 30 high with (3.553934904655 × 10^20) on top ie: 10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^(3.553934904655 × 10^20)

Comment: ----------- :-)  (<grin>)  Well done!

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(0) = 5$, let's substitute $x = 1$ in your definition, in order to get

$$f(1) = f(0) + 2^{f(0) + 1}$$

And since $f(0) = 5$ we get

$$f(1) = 5 + 2^{6} = 69$$

From here we are able to derive every other value for $f(x)$. Say we want to go on with $f(2)$, then $x = 2$ hence

$$f(2) = f(2-1) + 2^{f(2-1)+1} \rightarrow f(2) = f(1) + 2^{f(1) + 1}$$

From before, $f(1) = 69$ hence

$$f(2) = 69 + 2^{70}$$

Just to be clear,

$$2^{70} = 1180591620717411303424$$

and $$f(2) = 1180591620717411303493$$

Going up to $f(32)$ will give you a hugely large result...

Just to say, $f(3)$ will be this large:

$$f(3) = f(2) + 2^{f(2) + 1}$$

That is

$$f(3) = 1180591620717411303493 + 2^{1180591620717411303494}$$

(overflow.)